# Display (wrap) all items under each other only when there isn't space to fit them all single line (without media query)

Tags: css, flexbox

What is simplest possible and most versatile way of making following to work (ideally without exact media queries):

- display items next to each other = on the single line (when space for all available)
- display items under each other when we cannot display them in single line

Example:

Longer screen - everything fits single line:

```
| AAAA BBBB CCCC | // ok - fits
```

Smaller screen (no space for displaying in single line), so we want to display all under each other:

```
| AAAA      | // ok - single column
| BBBB      |
| CCCC      |
```

(Not desired effect) Unwanted effect which can be seen when using `flex-wrap`:

```
| AAAA BBBB | // nope - wrapped partially :(
| CCCC      |

display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

We might achieve similar desired effects using media query, but that would require knowing specific breakpoint. So I am trying to find solution only by using `flexbox`, `grid` or something similar without need to use media queries. Is there a solution ?

Comment: Would like to know if any such method exists, I have been facing this issue lately and managing to alter the flex-direction to column for smaller devices using media queries.

Answer (score 0):

If media queries is not an option, the only other solution would be to use Javascript.
Using flex you would basically switch between row and column based on the container width.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container')
// -->Change: state from row to column based on client width
if (container.clientWidth < container.scrollWidth) {
  container.classList.add('flex-column');
} else {
  container.classList.add('flex-row');
}
```

```css
.container { display: flex; }
.flex-row { flex-direction: row; }
.flex-column { flex-direction: column; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB </div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, wanted to figure out Css only solution but really seems this might be a problem. For JS solution we also need to add DOM changes listener to do recalculations when resizing browser window.